# Сброс выбора, если выбран другой элемент во 2-ом ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется приложение на WPF, в нем есть два `ListBox`.
Мне нужно сделать так, что бы при выборе какого либо элемента в одном из `ListBox`, сбрасывалось выделение у другого и наоборот.

Пытался на каждое повесить событие `SelectionChanged` и в нем `SelectedIndex = -1`, но получилось бредово, ибо срабатывало событие (естественно) у обоих `ListBox`-ов, что приводило к сбрасыванию выделения у обоих (после приходилось заново выбирать)

В общем прошу вашей помощи в решение этого вопроса!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего, наверное, так:

```
void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox orig = (ListBox)sender;
    if (orig.SelectedItems.Count == 0) // выделения нет
        return;
    ListBox other = (sender == FirstListBox) ? SecondListBox : FirstListBox;
    other.UnselectAll();
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ваш вариант подошел как надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться оператором `switch`, опираясь на то, что в WPF у элементов управления есть имена.

```
switch ((sender as ListBox).Name)
{
    case "listBox1": listBox2.SelectedIndex = -1; break;
    case "listBox2": listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1; break;
}
```

Comment: Если это должно вызываться событием SelectionChanged, то получается зацикливание, приводящий в итоге к сбросу всех выделений. Как я собственно и писал выше. Возьмем к примеру, выделим что нибудь в первом ListBox и выделим после что нибудь во втором. Результат: В первом выделение пропадет, а во втором даже не выделится (приходится второй раз жать для выделения)